# How can I count the average from Spark RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a problem with Spark Scala which I want count the average from the Rdd data,I create a new RDD like this,

```
[(2,110),(2,130),(2,120),(3,200),(3,206),(3,206),(4,150),(4,160),(4,170)]
```

I want to count them like this,

```
[(2,(110+130+120)/3),(3,(200+206+206)/3),(4,(150+160+170)/3)]
```

then,get the result like this,

```
   [(2,120),(3,204),(4,160)]
```

How can I do this with scala from RDD? 
I use spark version 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use aggregateByKey.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((2,110),(2,130),(2,120),(3,200),(3,206),(3,206),(4,150),(4,160),(4,170)))
val agg_rdd = rdd.aggregateByKey((0,0))((acc, value) => (acc._1 + value, acc._2 + 1),(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))
val sum = agg_rdd.mapValues(x => (x._1/x._2))
sum.collect
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `groupByKey` in this case.like this

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((2,110),(2,130),(2,120),(3,200),(3,206),(3,206),(4,150),(4,160),(4,170)))
val processedRDD = rdd.groupByKey.mapValues{iterator => iterator.sum / iterator.size}
processedRDD.collect.toList
```

Here, `groupByKey` will return the `RDD[(Int, Iterator[Int])]`  then you can simply apply average operation on `Iterator`

Hope this works for you

Thanks

Comment: It would strongly recommend aggregateByKey or combineByKey. Your solutions is ok, but may cause Out Of Memory Errors

Comment: Thanks @T.Gawęda when it comes to optimization yes my code lacks there I thought it is small scenerio

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.combineByKey()` to compute average:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq((2,110),(2,130),(2,120),(3,200),(3,206),(3,206),(4,150),(4,160),(4,170)))

val sumCountPair = data.combineByKey((x: Int) => (x.toDouble,1),
                                     (pair1: (Double, Int), x: Int) => (pair1._1 + x, pair1._2 + 1), 
                                     (pair1: (Double, Int), pair2: (Double, Int)) => (pair1._1 + pair2._1, pair1._2 + pair2._2))

val average = sumCountPair.map(x => (x._1, (x._2._1/x._2._2)))
average.collect()
```

here `sumCountPair` returns type `RDD[(Int, (Double, Int))]`, denoting: `(Key, (SumValue, CountValue))`. The next step just divides sum by the count and returns `(Key, AverageValue)`

Comment: Your and Alex 's answer are the best - they don't need to group every element of partition on one node