# Traversing RDD Key Value pairs when having several Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I currently new to Spark and I'm using Scala. 
Im having some trouble with traversing a `RDD Key Value` pairs.
Im got a TSV file, file1,  with among other things `Country Name`, `Latittude` and `Longitude` and I got so far;

```
val a = file1.map(_.split("\t")).map(rec => (rec(1), (rec(11).toDouble, rec(12).toDouble)))
```

Where `rec(1)` is country name and `rec(11)` is longitude, and `rec(12)` is latitude.
And as far as I understand a is now a key-value pair with `rec(1)` being key and rec(11) and rec(12) are values. 
I have managed to test that `a.first._1 gives` the first Key
`a.first._2._1` gives the first value for the key.
`a.first._2._2` gives the second value for the key.

My goal is to at least manage to get the average of all the `rec(11)` with the same key, and the same with `rec(12)`. So my thought was to sum them all and then divide with the number of key-value pairs with that key.

Could someone help me with what i should do next? I tried with `map`, `flatValueMap`, `valueMap`, `groupByKey` and so on, but i cant seem to manage to sum `rec(11)`'s and `rec(12)`'s at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the average from Spark RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171294/how-can-i-count-the-average-from-spark-rdd)

Comment: I would suggest you to used reduceByKey. [pyspark explanation of reducebykey with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `groupByKey` and then the `agg` operation with `avg`

Here is a quick example:

Original DF:

```
+------------+-----+
|country code|pairs|
+------------+-----+
|          ES|[1,2]|
|          UK|[2,3]|
|          ES|[4,5]|
+------------+-----+
```

Performing the operation:

```
df.groupBy($"country code").agg(avg($"pairs._1"), avg($"pairs._2"))
```

Result:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|country code|avg(pairs._1)|avg(pairs._2)|
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|          ES|          2.5|          3.5|
|          UK|          2.0|          3.0|
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> > My goal is to at least manage to get the average of all the rec(11) with the same key, and the same with rec(12)

You can proceed as below (commented for clarity)

```
a.mapValues(x => (x, 1))    //putting counter to the values of (k, (v1, v2)) as (k, ((v1, v2), 1))
  .reduceByKey{case(x,y) => ((x._1._1+y._1._1, x._1._2+y._1._2), x._2+y._2)}  //summing separately all the values of v1, all the values of v2 and the counter of same key
  .map{case(x, y)=> (x, (y._1._1/y._2, y._1._2/y._2))}  //finding the average i.e. deviding the sum of v1 and v1 by counter sum separately
```

this is all explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706